# Qual a diferença entre "mock" e "stub"?

Tags: testes, testes-de-unidade, testes-automatizados

- Em quais situações devem ser usados?
- Qual a diferença entre eles?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

### Qual a diferença entre mock e stub?

Enquanto um `stub` apenas provê respostas prontas para as chamadas que serão feitas durante o teste, o `mock` vai mais além e, além de prover as respostas, também valida as chamadas - ele conhece o comportamento esperado do sistema e testa este comportamento.

Assim, ao substituir um componente durante os testes, um `stub` teria a seguinte responsabilidade:

- **Se** o teste invocar o método A, retorno B.
- **Se** o teste invocar o método X, retorno Y.

Enquanto um `mock` teria a seguinte responsabilidade:

- O teste **deve** invocar primeiro o método A, passando o valor 1 como parâmetro, daí retorno B.
- O teste **deve depois** invocar o método X, passando o valor 2 como parâmetro, daí retorno Y.
- Se o teste não seguir exatamente esta sequência, ele **falha**.

Então podemos colocar na lista de diferenças o fato de que um `mock` é mais **complexo** que um `stub`.

É comum desenvolvedores usarem frameworks de mocks (JMock, EasyMock, Mockito, ...) apenas como stubs (não validam a interação entre os testes e o componente "mockado"). Neste caso o framework é especializado em mocks, mas conceitualmente está sendo utilizado um stub e não um mock.

Também não é incomum desenvolvedores chamarem de "mock" todos os tipos de dublês. E não há nada de tão errado nisso desde que de coração você conheça as diferenças e a complexidade trazida por cada tipo.

### Em quais situações usar um é mais vantajoso que usar o outro?

Estabelecido que ambos servem para substituir componentes reais (eles são "dublês" destes componentes) durante os testes, e entendida a diferença entre eles, fica nítido quando usar um e quando usar outro:

- Use `stub` para testar se um código, dada uma determinada entrada (respostas prontas dos métodos do stub), produz determinada saída.
- Use `mock`para testar se um código se **comporta** da maneira esperada no que tange a interações com o componente que o mock está substituindo.

### Um outro dublê na história:

Algumas vezes, além de prover respostas prontas, queremos saber se o teste de fato invocou um método do componente substiuído, ou mesmo quantas vezes ele invocou, mas não precisamos ser tão rígidos a ponto de verificar a sequência das chamadas ou o valor dos parâmetros, neste caso colocamos algum estado simples no `stub` (contador de chamadas do método, por exemplo) e obtemos assim um `spy` - um outro tipo de dublê que fica entre o `stub` e o `mock`, com alguns benefícios do segundo e quase toda a simplicidade do primeiro.

### Concluindo:

Usamos os diferentes tipos de dublês conforme a necessidade dos nossos testes, e damos preferência aos tipos menos complexos pois são menos acoplados ao código de produção, mais claros para serem entendidos, mais fáceis de receber manutenção.

Uma lista de dublês por ordem crescente de complexidade seria:

- 1º `Dummy`
- 2º `Fake` - o Fake pode ser bastante complexo (como um banco de dados em memória ou um servidor de aplicativos embarcado) mas não é acoplado ao seu código de produção então por isso é tido como de baixa complexidade.
- 3º `Stub`
- 4º `Spy`
- 5º `Mock`

O caminho para conseguir usar dublês em pouca quantidade ou usar os de complexidade mais baixa é a constante atenção ao design do sistema.

Answer (score 25):

Acho que a referência canônica sobre o assunto é o [artigo do Martin Fowler](http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html). Ele mostra a diferença entre 4 tipos de substitutos:

#### Dummy

São objetos usados para preencher uma lista de parâmetros quando o que contém neles não é relevante. Estes objetos não serão usados de fato.

#### Fake

São objetos com implementações reais, mas que não fazem exatamente o que se espera em ambiente de produção.

#### Stubs

São objetos criados para facilitar os testes dando respostas pré-determinadas e fazendo operações que fornecem informações adicionais do uso do método em teste. É mais importante dar facilidades para o teste acontecer com tranquilidade do que executar o teste, tanto que ele não tem como função fazer o teste falhar. Usado para **substituir estados**.

#### Mocks

São objetos com implementações **especificando** como é esperado que um método seja usado em código real. É com eles que você **substitui comportamentos**.

## Conclusão

As escolhas dependem um pouco do estilo como você faz seus testes. Eu sei que muita gente não vai gostar desta resposta, mas apesar de eu gostar das coisas corretas, acho tudo isto muito exagerado para a maioria dos projetos. Não estou desfazendo das ferramentas, mas isso muitas vezes parece NoSQL. Dá muito o que falar, mas poucos realmente precisam disto tudo. Só reforço que pensar bem na sua arquitetura e testar sua implementação é fundamental.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, e eu também concordo com sua conclusão! As vezes nos prendemos demais a esses conceitos e deixamos tudo muito mais complexo! (Eu acredito que em alguns projetos, essa complexidade é invariavelmente necessária, mas também sei que é possível ter bom senso e investir na arquitetura, tornando testes mais simples)