# Teste unitário / Mock de uma consulta JPA

Tags: java, jpa, testes-de-unidade, mock, criteria

Olá, como faço pra gerar um teste unitário/mock de uma consulta com JPA/Criteria ?

O que consigo garantir mockando meus objetos? Estrutura da tabela? O que devo mockar?

A consulta é muito simples, apenas um `select * from` na tabela/classe `Teste`

No caso de minha criteria ter condições no where, faz diferença para o mock?

No caso preciso de teste uniátio, não pode ser teste de integração.

Segue abaixo o código que quero testar, é um método genérico que retorna todos os registros de uma determinada tabela/entidade:

```
public List<T> findAll(Class<T> entityClass) {
        CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<T> cq = cb.createQuery(entityClass);
        Root<T> root = cq.from(entityClass);
        cq.select(root);

        TypedQuery<T> query = entityManager.createQuery(cq);
        return query.getResultList();
}
```

Quero testar que dada uma determinada classe, eu consiga retornar todos os registros da tabela.

Comment: Mas o que é que você quer testar? Quando escrevemos um teste automatizado, procuramos saber por exemplo se *"dada uma certa entrada o código produz uma certa saída"* ou se *"dadas determinadas condições o sistema se comporta de tal maneira"*. Também já escrevi testes para garantir que queries em string não quebrem depois de rafatoramento. Então, dependendo do objetivo, você tem algumas opções diferentes - como por exemplo não testar :-) O que você espera saber a partir do resultado o seu teste?

Comment: Melhorei a pergunta :) Quero testar que dada uma determinada classe, eu consiga retornar todos os registros da tabela.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para testar se o método *findAll* cumpre o seu papel de retornar todas as entidades de um dado tipo, **a melhor opção é disparar esta consulta contra um banco de dados de verdade**.

Explico: você está testando uma implementação bem próxima do banco de dados. Entre o seu código e o banco, só existe o framework JPA (EclipseLink, Hibernate, *whatever*). Como não faz sentido testar estes frameworks nem o banco de dados, você tem que deixar estes componentes executarem o seu trabalho para ver se teu código consegue, a partir da interação com eles, entregar o resultado esperado.

**Em alguns projetos, este seu método sequer seria testado** porque o custo em testá-lo é grande (grande dependência de outros componentes da arquitetura) e o valor em testá-lo é pequeno (o código em si faz muito pouco, não há regras importantes ali a serem validadas). Nestes projetos, em vez de escrever um teste para este método, este método é que seria *mockado*, ou seja, seria subsituído por outra coisa ao testar outro código que dependa dele.

**Mas existem outros projetos onde a regra é que 100% do código seja coberto por testes** (*"100% de cobertura"*); e há ainda a possibilidade de você querer escrever este tipo de método usando **TDD** (onde você primeiro escreveria o teste e depois o método *findAll* para passar no teste). Neste caso, como fazer?

## Você pode usar um *Fake* em vez de usar um *Mock*

Apesar de que é natural chamar tudo de "mock", talvez caiba aqui uma diferenciação entre estes dois tipos de ***dublês*** (*doubles*) dentro do seu caso específico:

<sub>Nesta [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/36928/14584) você tem uma lista de outros tipos de dublês.</sub>

### Mock

> O mock valida as interações do código testado com o componente que o mock está substituindo.

No seu exemplo, um mock substituiria o *EntityManager* e os demais objetos que ele entrega, e validaria se foram chamados os métodos *getCriteriaBuilder*, *createQuery*, *getResultList*, etc.

Veja que isso não se aplica porque você pode querer substituir todo este código que você tem hoje por uma única linha, por exemplo:

```
public List<T> findAll(Class<T> entityClass) {
    return entityManager.createQuery(String.format("select t from %s t", 
        entityClass.getSimpleName()), entityClass).getResultList();
}
```

Se você estivesse utilizando o conceito de mock, o teste deste método falharia embora o método ainda cumprisse o seu papel. Além disso, você vai querer testar outros métodos como este, só que mais complexos (utilizando filtro, por exemplo).

De maneira geral, apesar de chamarmos tudo de "mock", raramente um verdadeiro mock ajuda muito. Ele é complexo e a demanda por ele muitas vezes indica um problema de design ou um objetivo obtuso para o teste que se está escrevendo.

### Fake

> O fake é um tipo de dublê que tem uma implementação completa do componente que se está substituindo.

Ele é utilizado por ser mais adequado aos testes do que o componente real (por ser mais rápido, por exemplo) mas não poderá ser usado em produção por conta de outros requisitos (o cliente prefere usar outro componente ou este que usamos como fake não suporta a carga de produção, por exemplo).

Você usaria um fake aqui para substituir o banco de dados. Os bancos de dados que tenho utilizado com sucesso para isso são o [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) e o [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/).

A vantagem destes bancos de dados em relação a um SGBD mais *enterprise* (como Oracle e MS SQL Server) é que **eles podem ser utilizados totalmente em memória** e dentro do mesmo processo dos testes, eliminando a necessidade de comunicação entre processos ou acesso à rede e eliminando o acesso a disco, o que torna os testes muito mais rápidos.

O processo de testes usando um banco de dados em memória como dublê *fake* é o seguinte:

- O projeto conta com uma configuração de acesso a banco alternativa, que é utilizada apenas durantes os testes automatizados. Esta configuração, naturalmente, aponta para o banco de dados em memória.
- No início dos testes, o banco de dados é automaticamente criado em memória a partir das definições das entidades do seu projeto.
- No início de cada teste, ou seja, na preparação para o teste, você insere no banco as entidades que serão utilizadas por aquele teste em particular, e as deleta no final do teste ou simplesmente faz rollback da transação.

## Conslusão

É preciso ter claro o objetivo do teste que se está implementando.

Existem vários [tipos de dublês](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/36928/14584) para serem utilizados em testes automatizados e o **mock** na maioria das vezes é o menos indicado.

Um dublê do tipo **fake**, por outro lado, pode ser muito útil para testar implementações de acesso ao banco de dados ou para testes de serviços (que atravessam várias camadas da arquitetura).

O que você consegue testar com melhor performance utilizando um banco de dados *fake* é:

- Se as queries continuam funcionando depois de mudar nomes de entidades e atributos ou depois de mudar nomes de tabelas e colunas no banco de dados.
- Se a sua implementação de acesso aos dados (repositórios ou DAOs) continua funcionando depois de mudar uma estratégia de consulta, como a substituição que mostrei para o seu código original.
- E pode também executar testes de serviços, os quais atravessam várias camadas da arquitetura, inclusive o banco de daddos.

Comment: Excelente resposta, esclareceu várias dúvidas. A parte no qual você menciona que meu código a ser testado deveria ser mockado por outro teste me ajudou muito a entender o que devo testar.

Comment: Para implementar um banco de dados Fake, o DbUnit - http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/ poderia ser utilizado?

Comment: @BrunoGasparotto Eu não conheço essa ferramenta. Dando uma lida rápida parece bacana. De fato ter que inserir os registros antes de cada teste é trabalhoso então geralmente construimos bibliotecas só pra agilizar e simplificar isso. Poder carregar uma base pronta antes de cada teste parece facilitar. Há que se preocupar entretanto com a abstração do teste - se eu insiro o registro no próprio teste, fica óbvio enteder por que o teste espera determinado resultado, mas se os registros já estiverem lá o teste está acoplado àquele conjunto de registros "ocultos".

Comment: @BrunoGasparotto Também vem a tentação de usar o mesmo conjunto de registros para vários testes, então quando um teste passa a precisar de um conjunto ligeiramente diferente ele pode modificar o conjunto e prejudicar outro teste ou pode criar um novo conjunto muito semelhante até termos conjuntos demais e talvez não sabermos mais quais são úteis e quais não são. Enfim, há que se estudar a ferramenta e analisar os prós e contras para o projeto que se tem em mãos.

Comment: @Caffé Você insere os registros à cada teste. Todo o banco de dados é populando antes dos testes rodarem, e sofre um rollback ou é simplesmente destruído após os testes. Você pode ter um conjunto de registros para vários testes, ou para um teste em específico, ou seja, você pode ter quantos conjuntos quiser e utilizar onde e quando quiser.

Comment: @Caffé Pelo que entendi da sua resposta, a ferramenta se encaixa na técnica proposta, desde que seja utilizada com cuidado e sem acoplamento entre os testes. Correto?

Comment: @BrunoGasparotto Sim, correto. Não sei se no seu penúltimo comentário você se refere à minha resposta, então só esclarecendo: eu insiro antes de cada teste o conjunto de registros necessário àquele teste, e os deleto quando o teste termina ou faço rollback da transação. Quando se usa uma única instância de DB (fake ou não) para todos os testes, se quiser rodar em paralelo há que tomar cuidado com a interferência que os registros de um teste podem ter em outro; uma maneira de resolver isso é manter cada teste na sua própria transação. A ferramenta que vc apontou parece cuidar bem desse aspecto.