# Desenvolver testes de integração corretamente

Tags: java, junit, testes-funcionais

Estamos escrevendo diversos testes para a aplicação, há `testes unitários` e começamos `testes de integração`. 
 Toda a comunicação com o DAO é mockada, porém quando eu testo a API eu devo testar novamente os casos que **já foram testados** no service?

Por exemplo:
API

```
@RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Validacao create() {
        Validacao validacao = new Validacao()
                .setDataAtualizacao(DateTime.nowISODate())
                .setDataCriacao(DateTime.nowISODate())
                .setEmail(activeUser.getUser().getEmail())
                .setInstancia(activeUser.getInstancia().getInstancia());

        validacaoService.create(validacao);

        return validacao;
    }
```

Service

```
public Validacao create(Validacao validacao) {
        validacao = validacaoDAO.save(validacao);
        if (validacao == null) {
            throw new InternalServerErrorException("Ocorreu um erro ao criar a validação.");
        }
        return validacao;
    }
```

No teste unitário do Service, **já há um caso de teste caso a validação seja nula**. Esse teste deve se repetir novamente no teste de integração? Não é uma redundância?
Há casos em que o meu Service utiliza outro Service, isso deve ser mockado ou crio uma nova instância?

Comment: O intuito dos testes de integração é, como o nome indica, testar como os vários componentes/camadas funcionam(integram) em conjunto. Por isso não devem incidir nas questões particulares de cada componente/camada, questões essas que devem ser testadas através de testes unitários .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Quando eu testo a API eu devo testar novamente os casos que já foram testados no service?

Não, não deve.

O problema não é a redundância no sentido de o mesmo código ser executado por testes em diferentes níveis. Os problemas são:

- **Você está explicitamente testando a mesma regra duas vezes.**
- **Você está testando em uma camada do sistema as regras de outra camada.**

Veja, lançar exceção no caso de não poder salvar a *Validação* é uma regra do "service", então está correto você testar esta regra ao testar este service. Mas você não deveria testar esta regra na camada acima ("API") pois esta não é uma regra desta camada.

Mesmo que a gente simplifique e troque o termo "camadas" por "objetos", no seu teste você está verificando em um objeto uma regra que é responsabilidade de outro objeto, e é por isso que você ficou com essa sensação estranha de estar testando duas vezes a mesma coisa.

A sua API não está fazendo muita coisa, é difícil decidir o que testar ali. Nestes casos, geralmente, eu não testaria nada. Se não sei o que testar, por que vou escrever um teste?

Se, por outro lado, o projeto exige 100% de cobertura de testes, você pode testar se a API retorna um objeto *Validação* com as propriedades preenchidas conforme o esperado, assim você cobriria as linhas desta API sem testar algo que não seja a responsabilidade dela e manteria os 100% de cobertura.

## Outras notas sobre o seu código - *Exceções*

Em *ValidacaoDAO.save()* você está retornando *null* como código de erro. *Null* é um código de erro ruim.

> Se um método não conseguiu fazer o seu trabalho (não conseguiu realizar o que o seu nome sugere) ele deve ou lançar uma exceção ou retornar um código de erro (caso a sua decisão de design seja trabalhar com códigos de erro em vez de exceções).

A semântica de *null* é *"valor desconhecido"* ou *"não encontrado"* ou *"inexistente"*, e isso por si só não sugere um erro (eventualmente o consumidor pode decidir que isso é um erro dado o contexto).

Pode ser útil retornar *null* em um método *find*, por exemplo, indicando que o que era procurado não foi encontrado; e então o código consumidor decide o que fazer, por exemplo não fazendo nada ou lançando uma exceção caso aquilo que era procurado devesse, no determinado contexto, estar lá.

De qualquer modo, não me parece que você esteja interessada em códigos de erro, uma vez que você está de fato lançando uma exceção ao detectar um *null*. Neste caso, em vez de retornar *null*, o método *ValidacaoDAO.save()* deveria ele próprio lançar a exceção se não conseguir fazer o seu trabalho. Ou ainda, ele não deveria explicitamente lançar exceção nenhuma mas apenas deixar propagar uma exceção que porventura venha a impedí-lo de realizar o seu trabalho.

## Conclusão

Fatalmente, ao testar uma camada superior, as regras das camadas inferiores entrarão em ação. Mas um teste deve explicitamente verificar apenas as regras da camada ou objeto que ele está testando, e não deve verificar as regras específicas das camadas abaixo que em tese ele não conhece. Exemplo:

API:

```
void facaAlgo() {
    if (condicaoRuim_X) {
        throw new ExceptionA("As condições estavam desfavoráveis na API");
    }
    Service.facaAlgo();
}
```

Service:

```
void facaAlgo() {
    if (condicaoRuim_Y) {
        throw new ExceptionB("As condições estavam desfavoráveis no Service");
    }
}
```

Agora, ao testar o "service", eu verifico a exceção *ExceptionB* e ao testar a API eu verifico a *ExceptionA*.

Se não existisse nenhuma lógica na API, então eu poderia:

- ou não testar este método da API;
- ou testar apenas o caso feliz, validando os resultados no caso de tudo der certo, ignorando as regras específicas das camadas abaixo.

Quanto a *mocks*, use o mínimo possível. Eles dão muito trabalho e podem tornar a nossa vida infeliz, que é inverso do objetivo dos testes automatizados. Veja nestas respostas um pouco mais sobre mocks e outros "dublês":

- [Qual a diferença entre mock & stub?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/36928/14584)
- [Teste unitário / Mock de uma consulta JPA](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/56616/14584)

Comment: Ótima resposta! Testar já é algo bem tedioso e ainda ter de usar mocks todo o tempo. Uma observação do DAO, foi definido que sua função é apenas a comunicação com o banco, toda e qualquer parte lógica é responsabilidade do Service

Comment: @DanielaMarquesdeMorais Havia um tempo que eu escrevia os testes como sendo a cereja do bolo, o toque final para entregar um trabalho completo. Eu ainda acho que os testes de código são essenciais para entregar um trabalho completo, mas não acho mais que sejam a cereja do bolo - ao contrário, são a base dele. Assim como você, eu acho um tédio ter que escrever testes depois do código pronto - então eu faço diferente, escrevo os testes antes :-) Recomendo dar uma estudada em TDD (leia o livro do Kent Beck, eu acho que você vai gostar).

Answer (score 1):

Não se preocupe com redundância. Testes de integração são pra testar como os vários componentes do seu sistema trabalham em conjunto.

Principalmente casos de falha. Na realidade os testes são o lugar perfeito pra ver o que acontece se estourar uma exceção três ou mais camadas abaixo do serviço sendo testado.

Persistência e acesso a serviços externos (SOAP, REST, JMS, etc) podem ser mockados, mas eu prefiro usar o quanto eu puder dos serviços reais em testes de integração.

Finalmente, cuidado com os academicismos. Faça o que funciona pro seu projeto, sem medo de quebrar as regras.

PS.: Se isso for um trabalho pra sua faculdade, se professor vai falar que eu estou errado e te dar uma nota baixa.

Comment: Realmente mas me preocupo principalmente se tiver boas práticas (já que não é minha área), é perigoso criar testes mal feitos e depois prejudicar a manutenção e o próprio resultado do teste

Comment: Mais perigoso é não ter teste nenhum.

Comment: E que história é essa de "não é minha área"? Você desenvolve, você escreve testes... Esse lance de pegar uma pessoa, ou uma área, e dedicar fazer testes exclusivamente é coisa de quem acha que software se faz em linha de montagem.

Escrever testes deve fazer parte da sua rotina como desenvolvedor, você não tem que depender de outras pessoas pra testar seu código. Não precisa ser um fanático do TDD, mas escrever testes te facilita a vida.

QA deve ser uma responsabilidade da equipe como um todo.