# Quais as diferenças entre mocks e fakes?

Tags: testes, mock

Quando implementamos testes em um software, **Mocks** e **Fakes** são duas técnicas ou abordagens para isolar o código sendo testado do resto do sistema.

Sem aprofundar no assunto:

- Mocks são como cascas vazias com comportamentos predefinidos, tal como: *ao chamar o método X, retorne o valor Y*
- Fakes são objetos totalmente ou parcialmente funcionais implementados especialmente para os testes que visam simular o funcionamento do sistema, mas de forma relativamente isolada.

Mas quais seriam as diferenças relevantes entre os dois conceitos para a correta implementação de testes? Alguns aspectos relevantes:

- Quais tipos de testes (unitário, funcional, integração) funcionam melhor com os dois?
- Existem situações específicas onde é mais evidente que vale a pena usar um ou outro? Exemplos em qualquer linguagem são bem-vindos.
- Qual deles ou em que sentido eles são melhores ou piores quando há mudanças no sistema, isto é, para dar manutenção nos testes?

> **Update:** eu não quero a definição dos conceitos, isto já está na pergunta. O que eu quero são diferenças na aplicação, como descrito nos tópicos acima, mas não limitado a eles. Alguém que tenha usado ambos deve ter uma ideia do que estou falando.

Comment: A pergunta original não falava nisto, mas já respondi o que é, os detalhes ainda não: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/36756/101

Comment: Eu acho até que dá para passar, mas achei curioso como o pessoal anda fechando qualquer coisa e ninguém ousou dar um votinho pra fechar essa e até outras. Anda brincando com o limite do pessoas :) O pessoal vota torno mesmo :)

Comment: @bigown Confesse que fiz de propósito. :D  Mas conforme minha atualização, não estou perguntando sobre as definições dos conceitos e sim dos detalhes de como aplicar.

Comment: @utluiz [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/311208/27190) tem uma pergunta pratica a respeito do assunto. Acredito eu que ela tenha uma forte relação com sua pergunta e pode ajuda a compreender melhor as dúvidas entre mocks e fakes.

Answer (score 4):

> Quais tipos de testes (unitário, funcional, integração) funcionam melhor com os dois?
>
> Existem situações específicas onde é mais evidente que vale a pena usar um ou outro? Exemplos em qualquer linguagem são bem-vindos.

Para **testes unitários**, os mocks são as principais escolhas e acredito também que os fakes tem seu lugar. Comumente, em testes unitários estamos testando o comportamento de uma classe específica e tentando ignorar ao máximo as dependências desta classe.

Neste ato de "ignorar" suas dependências, usamos o conceito de mock para apenas fazer com que estas dependências se comportem de determinada maneira para cada teste.

## Com Mock

Vamos a um exemplo em Java, usando o [Mockito](http://site.mockito.org). Digamos que quero testar um serviço `CreditoService` que depende de um `ParametroService` e que consulta um valor chamado `bonus` através desta classe de parâmetro. Neste caso estamos preocupados em testar a implementação de `CreditoService` e não nos interessa como o ParametroService funciona:

```java
ParametroService parametroService = mock(ParametroService.class);
when(parametroService.getBonus(any(Empresa.class))).thenReturn("10.00");
CreditoService creditoService = new CreditoService(parametroService);
```

No exemplo acima, eu simplesmente disse para o `parametroService` me retornar "10.00" ao consultar o `bonus` independente da `empresa` que a classe receba como parâmetro.

E a diferença principal que separa o Mock de um Fake é que com Mocks você consegue verificar e confirmar se determinadas ações ocorreram com aquele Mock, pois todas estas ações em cima do mock são gravadas. No exemplo anterior eu criei um mock e, embora tenha definido uma ação esperada por ele, não verifiquei se ele foi realmente chamado. Assim, eu posso também adicionar uma verificação que o método de bonus do parametroService foi chamado um certo número de vezes:

```java
verify(parametroService, times(1)).getBonus(any(Empresa.class));
```

## Com Fake

Neste mesmo exemplo, eu poderia usar um `Fake` do `ParametroService`. Digamos que, dependendo do valor que eu passar de `empresa`, eu gostaria que o `ParametroService` fizesse algo diferente internamente; qualquer tipo de lógica em cima da empresa. Por exemplo, se a empresa passada fosse uma filial, ela não teria um bonus. Podemos ter algo assim então:

```java
ParametroService parametroService = new ParametroServiceFake();
CreditoService creditoService = new CreditoService(parametroService);
```

Sendo `ParametroServiceFake` uma implementação da mesma interface `ParametroService` usada pela implementação real:

```java
class ParametroServiceFake implements ParametroService {
    String getBonus(Empresa empresa) {
         if (empresa.isFilial()) {
             return "0";
         }
         return "10.00";
    }
}
```

Em **testes de integração e funcionais** este conceito ainda existe, porém os Fakes costumam reinar.

Por exemplo, em um teste de integração eu posso criar um banco em memória ao fazer um `Fake` de um classe de repositório (*repository*), no qual os dados a serem inseridos em um suposto banco de dados são armazenados em um `Map` interno do Fake, que pode inclusive prover métodos de busca por este dado "salvo" no repositório.

Posso fazer o mesmo também ao fazer um `Fake` de uma classe usada para simular o comportamento de um `WebService`:

```java
 class WebServiceFake implements WebService {
    String consultarNomeCliente(String cpf) {
         if (cpf.equals("123.123.123-11"))
              return "Augusto Moraes Filho";
         return "";
    }
}
```

Como podem ver, é uma implementação funcional porém longe da real. Mas quando você precisa simular determinados comportamentos de sistemas externos, esta técnica vem a calhar.

Podemos também utilizar em testes de integração ou funcional mocks. No [Spring](https://spring.io) esta possibilidade existe e é bem acessível por meio do `@MockBean`, no qual você pode, em qualquer teste de integração/funcional, fazer um mock de qualquer classe injetável.

> Qual deles ou em que sentido eles são melhores ou piores quando há mudanças no sistema, isto é, para dar manutenção nos testes?

Em geral, os mocks dão menos manutenção, principalmente por causa do contexto que eles são inseridos: testes locais, unitários e isolados dos demais testes.

Já os Fakes exigem implementação de código funcional. **Se temos código implementado, temos manutenção**. E o problema só pióra quando um `Fake` precisa estar "alinhado" com os dados de outro `Fake`.

Vamos a um exemplo. Digamos que quero fazer um teste de integração que utilize dados de dois sistemas externos diferentes. Um deles tem os dados de pessoa e o outro da conta corrente. Temos então a pessoa "Eduardo", de CPF "123.123.123-11" e com a conta corrente "9876-0". Assim, posso ter um `Fake` para cada sistema. Até aqui, tudo bem.

Vamos ao problema agora. Se eu buscar pelo CPF do Eduardo no primeiro sistema, ele precisa vir. Assim como se eu fizer uma busca pelo CPF no segundo sistema, para ter sua conta corrente. Se, por acaso, um dos dois lados não trazer resultados ao buscar pelo CPF, meu teste falhará. Isto por si só fará com que eu precisa me preocupar que ambos Fakes tenham CPF com dados de pessoa e conta corrente e que ninguém, no futuro, "quebre" esta ligação entre ambos que existe no cenário real de uso.

Comment: A definição que eu tenho lido sobre "mocks" está em completo desalinho da sua resposta. Entretanto, não sei quem está certo, nem se há situações em que o contexto torna um certo e o outro errado.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado, compartilhe a definição que tem de mock. Talvez minha explicação não tenha sido clara, por isto (e há pedido do autor do tópico) trouxe exemplos na resposta.

Comment: Um dos cantos de leitura meu: https://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html ; ele pode não estar certo, mas ele é o Martin Fowler xD

Comment: hehehe, vou melhorar a parte do Mock, creio que a diferença crucial é que com Mocks você pode verificar se o que você esperava realmente ocorreu. Fora isto, estou tentando definir o `Mock` de acordo com o seu funcionamento e função nos frameworks dedicados a isto (EasyMock, Mockito, etc).