# Qual é a finalidade das Interfaces usadas em um Mock?

Tags: c#, testes-de-unidade, moq

Estou usando uma biblioteca chamada [Moq](https://github.com/moq/moq4) que serve para criação de mocks que serão usados em testes unitários.

No entanto, para criar um mock é necessário especificar uma interface, como no exemplo da pagina do projeto Moq:

```
var mock = new Mock<ILoveThisFramework>();
```

ou

```
var mock = new Mock<IQualquerInterface>();
```

[Mais exemplos](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart).

E é exatamente neste ponto que aparecem minhas dúvidas.

## Dúvidas

1. Qual é a finalidade das Interfaces usadas em um Mock?
2. Que tipo de relação a Interface tem com o Mock?
3. Porque usar uma interface ao invés de uma classe que representaria
   um objeto?

Comment: Não sei em específico sobre ele mas deve ter a ver com https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86484/101.

Comment: Relacionado: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9226323/mocking-a-class-vs-mocking-its-interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9226323/mocking-a-class-vs-mocking-its-interface)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na verdade, para criar um mock, você não precisa de uma interface. Você pode criar um mock de uma classe. O que vai definir é como você projetou a sua solução. Quando usar uma interface e quando usar uma classe vai entrar em uma outra discussão, que pode ser vista no link compartilhado pelo @Maniero.

Tentarei explicar com exemplos.

Imagine que você tem essa classe:

```
public class CalcularIdade {

    public int calcular(int anoNascimento) {
        Data data = new Data();
        int anoAtual = data.getAno();
        return anoAtual - anoNascimento;
    }
}
```

Agora imagine que por algum motivo você não consegue usar a classe `Data` no teste. Fazer esse teste vai ser difícil. Uma solução é fazer que a classe `Data` seja injetada na classe `CalcularIdade`. Dessa maneira será possível também injetar o mock da classe `Data`. Uma primeira alternativa seria essa:

```
public class CalcularIdade {

    private Data data;

    public CalcularIdade(Data data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public int calcular(int anoNascimento) {
        int anoAtual = data.getAno();
        return anoAtual - anoNascimento;
    }
}
```

A `Data` é passado como parâmetro para a classe `CalcularIdade`. Agora eu consigo passar o mock da classe `Data` para a classe `CalcularIdade`. A aplicação real ficaria dessa forma:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    CalcularIdade calcularIdade = new CalcularIdade(new Data());
    int idade = calcularIdade.calcular(1990);
    System.out.println(idade);
}
```

O teste ficaria dessa forma:

```
@Test
public void calcularTest() {
    Data dataStub = mock(Data.class);
    when(dataStub.getAno()).thenReturn(2018);

    int anoNascimento = 1990;

    CalcularIdade calcularIdade = new CalcularIdade(dataStub);
    int result = calcularIdade.calcular(anoNascimento);
    assertEquals(result, 28);
}
```

Eu fiz um mock de uma classe e vai funcionar perfeitamente bem. Perceba que essa pode não ser a melhor solução, mas o problema está no design da classe e não no teste.

Se futuramente eu desejar criar uma outra implementação para a classe `Data`, isso poderá ser feito, basta criar uma classe que herde de `Data`. Contudo, existirá um dependência da classe `CalcularIdade` com a classe `Data`. A depender da solução, essa dependência pode não ser um problema. Porém se for necessário remover a dependência, uma interface irá prover justamente isso. Ireir refatorar minha classe para que a classe `CalcularIdade` não dependa de implementação:

```
public class CalcularIdade {

    private IData iData;

    public CalcularIdade(IData data) {
        this.iData = data;
    }

    public int calcular(int anoNascimento) {
        int anoAtual = iData.getAno();
        return anoAtual - anoNascimento;
    }
}
```

Meu teste:

```
@Test
public void calcularTest() {
    IData dataStub = mock(IData.class);
    when(dataStub.getAno()).thenReturn(2018);

    int anoNascimento = 1990;

    CalcularIdade calcularIdade = new CalcularIdade(dataStub);
    int result = calcularIdade.calcular(anoNascimento);
    assertEquals(result, 28);
}
```

Se amanhã eu quiser uma nova implementação de IData, minha aplicação fica:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    CalcularIdade calcularIdade = new CalcularIdade(new NovaData());
    int idade = calcularIdade.calcular(1990);
    System.out.println(idade);
}
```

Poderia ser feito com classe? Sim. Porém existiria um acoplamento entre `Data` e `CalcularIdade`, com a interface esse acoplamento some.

Talvez a biblioteca que você esteja utilizando não permita criar mock de classe. Se esse for o caso, essa pode ser uma restrição para forçar o programador a criar um design melhor, porém essa não é uma restrição do mock conceitualmente falando.

Comment: A biblioteca permitir usar classe ao invés de interface. Mas agora entendi o motivo da interface, é para aumentar a testabilidade do projeto e deixar com um designer melhor.

Answer (score 0):

O Mock simula a funcionalidade/dados de uma classe, para que a biblioteca possa criar essa classe fake, ela utiliza a interface para implementar a classe com o parâmetros que você passa, dessa forma, a biblioteca consegue implementar os métodos com as características necessárias para os testes.