# Como se testa algo "intestável"?

Tags: java, testes, testes-de-unidade

Testar certos componentes de um sistema é simples se esse componente não tem dependências muito relevantes, como por exemplo, uma classe como essa:

```
public class Data {
    private final String _field;

    public Data(String field) {
        _field = field;
    }
    ....
}
```

Mas testar essa classe é simples porque ela é simplesmente uma estrutura de dados que não influencia em muita coisa exceto o estado que existe dentro dela mesma.

E se a classe faz coisas como conexão com a rede, leitura e escrita de arquivos (o que ainda por cima pode depender do estado do sistema de arquivos), conexão com bancos de dados, etc?

Como se prova em tempo de desenvolvimento que essas classes funcionam?

O caso da classe que manipula arquivos é até prático, mas e pra uma classe que depende de um serviço tão pouco amigável e imprevisível como rede?

Comment: Você está confundindo princípios, o objetivo dos testes não é deixar o sistema infálivel mas garantir que existam tratamentos para as eventuais falhas.

Comment: Em java se usa `try-catch` para para esse tipo de teste, sempre que perde a conexão com um servidor, ele libera um erro e vai para a exceção, e é ai que é decidido oque será feito em seguida (normalmente).

Comment: Se tem só uma estrutura de dados  não tem o que testar. Coloque um exemplo do que considera "intestável". Não consigo imaginar algo instestável. Existem coisas que não dá para testar facilmente de forma automatizada, mas nenhum dos citados na pergunta. Provas podem ser obtidas por [método formal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_methods), mas em geral não compensa o custo. É raro alguém querer provas.

Comment: @FelipeAssunção mas eu não afirmei que o objetivo dos testes é mostrar que um sistema é infalível, só perguntei se existe alguma forma de testar classes que dependem de recursos onde não se pode ter certeza da condição deles.

Comment: @bigown pense em qualquer classe que precise de rede: Como se testa se ela reage da forma que você quer se a conexão falha? Como testar se rela reage da forma que você quer se a conexão sucede? E mais: Como testar se ela se comporta da forma que você quer se a rede cair de repente? São condições nada determinísticas, onde você depende da sorte pra algo. É diferente de testar uma estrutura de dados.

Comment: Testes unitários é algo novo pra mim, mas pelo que entendo o principal objetivo é verificar se o código irá funcionar corretamente quando existe alterações no sistema que podem afetar de alguma forma o seu comportamento. Se existe uma falha na rede e é obrigatório para que seu sistema funcione, deverá ser tratado dentro de um bloco `try-catch`, não é algo que deveria ser testado em um teste unitário.

Comment: @Sid considerando seu exemplo: Se você precisa copiar um arquivo em rede(instáveis) se a rede estiver indisponível no momento como você gostaria que sua classe se comportasse? retorna exceção ou coloca o arquivo em uma fila pra aguardar a rede? qualquer comportamento que você desejar basicamente você só precisa garantir que durante a falha o sistema vai saber responder ao problema ou seja `testável`.

Comment: Vou repetir: não existe teste de estrutura de dados. Teste e exceção são coisas distintas. Veja isto: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/36745/101

Comment: @FelipeAssunção mas é aí que está. Um dos objetivos dos testes é qual? Oferecer um feedback imediato para que consertemos erros o quanto antes, porque as vezes o código que você escreveu nem sempre faz o que você pensa que faz, então você roda para ter certeza. "Simplesmente garanta no seu código que o programa irá fazer tal coisa se a conexão falhar", sim, mas como garantir isso o quanto antes?

Answer (score 9):

É uma boa pergunta. Vou me concentrar nas "subperguntas" (em diferente ordem) para elaborar uma resposta...

> ## E se a classe faz coisas como conexão com a rede, leitura e escrita de arquivos (o que ainda por cima pode depender do estado do sistema de arquivos), conexão com bancos de dados, etc?

### Nem tudo é teste unitário

A primeira coisa é que **não** estamos falando de testes unitários de verdade.

Testes unitários são isolados e em geral devem garantir que um método ou, no máximo, uma classe apresentam o comportamento esperado com base no conceito simples de **entrada, processamento e saída**, ou seja, data a entrada `X`, devo receber `Y` e assim por diante.

Em segundo ligar, é importante entender que nem tudo necessariamente precisa ser testado nos testes unitários. Para outras situações servem testes de integração, de sistema em outros tipos de teste.

### Testes de integração

Testes de integração servem para saber se as partes continuam funcionando quando colocadas em conjunto.

Nada impede de um teste de integração acessar arquivos, rede ou banco de dados. A questão importante aqui é *o quanto isso é confiável* para que fatores externos não influenciem o resultado dos testes, levando a falsos positivos ou falsos negativos.

Casos comuns são:

- Depender que um arquivo exista no disco: pode levar a problemas caso alguém esqueça de colocar o arquivo no local correto.
- Depender de um banco de dados existente: testes devem resetar o banco de dados a cada execução, caso contrário dados existentes podem interferir e problemas nunca serão detectados, tal como o caso de não existirem registros numa tabela.
- Depender de um serviço externo pela rede: se o teste precisa de um web service para funcionar, você pode prover um *endpoint* fictício, por exemplo.

### Testando entrada e saída

No caso de arquivos no disco, não é nada complicado e nem é errado que a classe de teste grave alguns arquivos no disco e execute uma rotina que vá ler os arquivos e gerar outros, sendo que no final você lê os arquivos gerados e vê se estão corretos.

Outra possibilidade é criar suas classes usando abstrações como `InputStream` e `OutputStream` ao invés de passar um `File` ou `Path`. Assim você testa suas rotinas de geração e leitura sem realmente usar o disco. Muito mais eficiente.

### Testando bancos de dados

Existe várias formas. A mais eficiente é usar um banco de dados em memória.

Outras formas é criar uma rotina que limpa e/ou restaura um banco de dados. O ideal é que o banco seja local, para evitar que várias pessoas executem o teste ao mesmo tempo e haja conflito.

Outra alternativa é usar um container como Vagrant para executar os testes de forma isolada e eficiente. Vagrant usa o VirtualBox e você pode configurar uma máquina virtual que simule o ambiente de produção.

### Testando a rede

Para testar como seu sistema reage a serviços externos, você pode criar um serviço local, inicializado durante os testes, que retorne valores fixos de acordo com o teste.

Se você tiver acesso ao WSDL ou à especificação do serviço esterno isso é até bem simples.

Se o seu sistema for distribuído você pode criar situações isoladas de stress para verificar se o código é resiliente. Por exemplo, se o seu sistema possui dois componentes que fazem o papel de produtor e consumidor e você quer testar se a comunicação funciona bem, pode criar um produtores e consumidores que geram e consomem mensagens uma grande quantidade de mensagens sem realizar um processamento pesado de verdade. No final você simplesmente verifica algum contador para saber se nenhuma mensagem foi perdida.

### O que você não precisa testar

De qualquer forma, existem coisas que você simplesmente não testa porque não faz parte do escopo do projeto.

No caso de arquivo, eu usei como exemplo o uso de `InputStream`, afinal você quer testar se o seu sistema é capaz de decodificar a entrada, não é? Ou será que agora você quer testar se a API do Java funciona?

No caso de um web service ou serviço de rede, você também não quer testar o sistema de terceiros, ou quer? Você não precisa e nem deve invocar sistemas de terceiros durante o teste. Você simplesmente assume que eles funcionam conforme alguma documentação, isto é, você manda `X` ele deve retornar `Y`. Se esse for o contrato, assuma que ele vai cumprir.

> ## O caso da classe que manipula arquivos é até prático, mas e pra uma classe que depende de um serviço tão pouco amigável e imprevisível como rede?

Eu sei que na prática vários erros em tempo de execução podem ocorrer que não são encontrados em testes isolados.

Aqui entram conceitos como MVP, *continuous delivery* ou protótipo de arquitetura.

Basicamente, para integrações com sistemas de terceiros você deve criar protótipos isolados para testar se a integração ocorre com sucesso.

Não espere o sistema estar funcionando para fazer isso!

Uma forma de fazer isso é criar um tipo de biblioteca em um projeto separado que possa ser chamado via linha de comando ou algo parecido. Isso não faz parte do projeto principal, portanto não atrapalha o ciclo de desenvolvimento. Entretanto, sempre que houver um problema ou mudança você pode executar os testes manualmente.

Além disso, com *releases* frequentes do sistema, priorizando as áreas de maior risco, você coloca essas partes que apresentam risco de falha em "produção" logo de cara e antecipa problemas.

> ## Como se prova em tempo de desenvolvimento que essas classes funcionam?

Aqui vai um resumo de tudo, mas antes de tentar provar que algo funciona, vamos pensar primeiro em como dividir tudo isso.

Primeiro, as funcionalidades do seu sistema precisam ser testadas de forma unitária. Se não é possível fazer isso, você tem um problema de modelagem.

Por exemplo, se você tiver algo do tipo:

```
rotina(arquivoEntrada, arquivoSaida) {
    String s = lerArquivo(arquivoEntrada)
    String r = processarArquivo(s)
    gravarResultado(r, arquivoSaida)
}
```

Você deve profundamente considerar mudar para algo como:

```
rotina(inputStream, outputStream) {
    Data data = ler(inputStream)
    Result result = processar(data)
    gravarResultado(result, outputStream)
}
```

Agora você pode testar cada rotina de forma independente.

Segundo, você não precisa testar tudo. Não carregue o fardo de testar a API do Java, por exemplo.

Terceiro, caso haja integrações com sistemas externos, você deve fazer três coisas:

1. Teste essas integrações manualmente o mais cedo possível para garantir que elas funcionam como esperado.
2. Coloque o código de teste num local separado, para que ele não atrapalhe o desenvolvimento do sistema principal.
3. Priorize colocar as integrações em produção o mais cedo possível de forma que problemas ocultos apareçam o mais cedo possível.

Finalmente, posso dizer que você não deve se preocupar em *provar* que tudo funciona. Claro que, quanto melhor forem seus testes, melhor será a qualidade do sistema.

Entretanto, sempre vão existir casos que não dá para antecipar e que muitas vezes somente a experiência e um pensamento analítico vão conseguir pegar. Um exemplo comum é que a leitura de disco, do banco ou integração com outros sistemas se torne um gargalo em relação ao desempenho.

Isso acontece porque seus testes podem estar 100% corretos, mas frequentemente nós testamos com uma massa de dados que dificilmente ultrapassa 10 elementos, quando não 2 ou 3.

Portanto, o "arquiteto" ou as pessoas mais experientes que participam do desenvolvimento da aplicação devem analisar clinicamente quais são os pontos críticos e determinar se serão necessários testes adicionais de carga, stress, resiliência, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Para isso que se usa mocking.
Irei explicar usando um exemplo:

obs: usarei C# para os exemplos de código, porém a sintaxe é bem parecida com a do Java logo ficará bem fácil de entender.

obs²: o C# possui a função de gerar automaticamente os getters/setters de propriedades (`public int Numero {get; set;`). Mas por baixo do capô funciona que nem no java: variáveis privadas com métodos para acessar e setar tais variáveis.

```
public class DataProcessing
{
    private Database _database;

    public DataProcessing(Database database)
    {
        _database = database;
    }
}
```

E a classe Database:

```
public class Database
{
    public List<int> Numbers { get; private set; }

    public Database()
    {
        //conecta-se ao db, puxa os dados e salva em Numbers
    }
}
```

Como pode ver, não é possível simplesmente criar uma instância de `Database` sem ser puxando os dados do banco, pois a propriedade `List<int> Numbers` possui o `set` privado. Claro, você poderia editar a classe `Database` para incluir um construtor que aceite uma list para salvar na propriedade porém esse construtor só seria útil para testes, e nunca seria usado durante o funcionamento normal da aplicação. Uma possível solução seria usar interfaces.

```
public interface IDatabase
{
    List<int> Numbers { get; }
}
```

A classe normal do banco:

```
public class Database : IDatabase
{
    public List<int> Numbers { get; private set; }

    public Database()
    {
        //conecta-se ao db, puxa os dados e salva em Numbers
    }
}
```

A única diferença é que agora a classe `Database` herda da interface `IDatabase`. Dessa maneira, é possível criar uma classe que também herda de `IDatabase` mas é usada para testes:

```
public class DatabaseMock : IDatabase
{
    public List<int> Numbers { get; private set; }

    public DatabaseMock()
    {
        Numbers = new List<int>
        {
            1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
        };
    }
}
```

Dessa maneira, em todos os seus testes, instâncias de DatabaseMock irão possuir os mesmos dados.

Só o que falta é mudar o construtor da `DataProcessing` de `Database` para `IDatabase`

```
public class DataProcessing
{
    private Database _database;

    public DataProcessing(IDatabase database)
    {
        _database = database;
    }

    public void SumNumbers()
    {
        //Process data
    }
}
```

Caso tenha dúvidas me informe que eu tento explicar melhor, caso queira também posso tentar passar o código para Java.

E isso você faria com qualquer coisa que possua dependências. Tenha em mente que você também poderia passar, no caso desse exemplo, um mock da Database com a propriedade nula e ver se suas classes que tem Database como dependência tratam esse problema da maneira correta.

Ps.: Meu uso do termo mock não é de acordo com a definição exata do mesmo. Eu deveria ter usado o termo dubles mas enfim. [Essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/36928/11425) explica bem isso (mais especificamente a diferença entre `stubs` e `mocks`).

Além disso existe um belo artigo que explica ainda em mais profundidade:
http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html

Comment: Então se trata de basicamente criar classes/componentes que vão criar um ambiente falso para ver como a classe se comporta? É possível fazer isso com coisas como redes ou algum recurso mais externo e instável?

Comment: Isso. A ideia do teste unitário é testar se aquela unidade específica de código se comporta corretamente, dado que todo o resto funciona. Por isso não há problema em forjar um ambiente ideal (ou uma falha).

Comment: Exatamente o que o @Pablo disse. A partir do momento que você sabe os possíveis estados de algo que queira simular (no caso de uma rede, por exemplo, pode ocorrer um problema de conexão ou envio de dados), você pode, além de tratar tais estados no seu código, testá-los para certificar-se que estão sendo tratados corretamente.

Essa é a beleza dos testes unitários, você não precisa tirar o cabo de rede pra ver se seu programa não vai explodir quando ocorrer uma falha de conexão :)

Comment: Eu prefiro ainda utilizar o Repository Pattern para trazer a abstração do meu mock para um nível acima, já que as classes de business não deveriam nem saber da existência de um banco de dados ou qualquer mecanismo de persistência.

Comment: @ViniciusZaramella Partilho de sua preferência porém achei que fazer o mesmo no exemplo deixaria-o muito extenso.

Answer (score 1):

Para corroborar com as explicações já dadas, gostariam de apontar três casos em que teste não fazem sentido na minha opinião.

Primeiro é em classes que representam apenas uma estrutura de dados, classe com apenas getters e setters.

Segundo são classes de controle, normalmente chamadas de Managers, Processor, etc. Essas classes normalmente só delegam tarefas para outras e servem como um facade para simplificar trabalho e diminuir repetição de código de quem vai utilizar seu código. Por não terem nenhuma regra de negócio em si a única coisas que se pode testar nessas classes é se uma sequencia de métodos foi de fato chamada. Porém esse tipo de teste apenas deixa seu código mais rígido a mudanças.

O terceiro é não testar código de terceiros. Se você está utilizando uma biblioteca de terceiros você deve confiar que eles testaram o código deles e que o código funciona do jeito esperado. Se ao utilizar uma biblioteca você começa a fazer testes que só checam a funcionalidade da biblioteca e não do seu código você está perdendo tempo.

Enfim, foque os teste unitários em classes que representam as regras de negócio e que certifique-se que essas classes estão isoladas de interfaces ( Http, Input de usuário...) e de mecanismos de persistência por uma camada de abstração.