# Qual o conceito de Stubs e de Drivers em testes de integração?

Tags: engenharia-de-software, testes

- Qual o conceito de driver e stubs em testes de integração, qual a diferença entre eles?
- Em quais situações devem ser usados?

Comment: Stub já tem aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/36745/101

Answer (score 5):

## Qual o conceito de driver e stub em testes de integração?

**Driver** e **Stub** são dublês (*doubles*, também conhecidos como *mocks*), cuja função é substituir um componente durante os testes de software, automatizados ou não.

Se falarmos do nível de testes automatizados implementados pelo próprio programador, a explicação do **stub** e outros dublês pode ser vista aqui: [Qual a diferença entre mock e stub?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/36928/14584)

Mas veja que neste nível de automação, onde usamos frameworks *xUnit* e escrevemos os testes na mesma linguagem que usamos para escrever o código de produção, não aparece o **Driver**.

O tipo de dublê **Driver** é utilizado em testes de *"caixa preta"*, que são testes realizados não sobre o código fonte mas sim contra as interfaces externas do sistema, como por exemplo formulários web ou APIs HTTP.

## Qual a diferença entre eles?

Considere uma arquitetura onde um **componente *A* depende do componente *B***. O componente B não faz nada sozinho - ele apenas é consumido pelo componente A.

Talvez você queira:

- testar os dois componentes trabalhando em conjunto;
- testar o componente **A** sem depender do funcionamento do componente **B** (talvez o componente B nem esteja disponível ao testar o A);
- ou talvez seja o inverso: você precisa testar o **B** mas o seu consumidor **A** não está disponível.

Isso te deixa com 3 cenários de testes possíveis (imagem retirada do [Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-stubs-and-drivers-in-software-testing)):

[image: Driver vs Stub in QA tests]

- **1)** O componente **A** é testado consumindo o componente **B** real, de modo que os dois componentes são testados neste cenário.
- **2)** Ao testar o componente **A**, a dependência **B** é substituída por um dublê (um componente substituto, utilizado apenas durante os testes). Neste cenário apenas o componente **A** está sendo testado.
- **3)** O componente **B** está sendo testado isoladamente sem o seu consumidor, o qual foi substituído por um dublê. Neste cenário, apenas o componente **B** está sendo testado.

#### Driver e Stub

Neste exemplo, o componente **A** é o consumidor, o orquestrador da operação sendo testada. Se eu quero testá-lo de maneira independente (ou se simplesmente eu não tenho a dependência ainda disponível), eu substituo esta dependência por um **Stub**, o qual deve dar respostas prontas pré-programadas.

Agora, se o foco do teste é justamente a dependência, o componente **B**, eu substituo o consumidor por um **Driver**, o qual vai tratar de simular o consumo do componente testado.

## Um exemplo

Para melhor assimilar este exemplo, podemos pensar o componente **A** como sendo um **aplicativo para smartphone** e o componente **B** como sendo uma **API HTTP** consumida por este aplicativo.

Assim, quando você vai testar o aplicativo, em vez de consumir a API real (por exemplo um complexo sistema backend) você cria um dublê que replica a API em questão fornecendo respostas prontas. Este dublê de API seria um **Stub**.

E quando você vai testar a API de fato, você substitui o aplicativo mobile por um software que simplifique e até automatize requisições Http. Este outro software seria o dublê do tipo **Driver**.

## Em quais situações devem ser usados?

Você pode utilizá-los ao testar um componente quando o outro não está disponível (é um recurso externo, tem alta complexidade, tem custo relevante para ser consumido, ainda não está pronto, etc.) ou mesmo quando ele está disponível mas você não quer que seu comportamento afete os resultados do teste de um outro componente.

## Por que não temos Driver nos testes unitários

A classificação **Driver** aparece mais no universo de **QA** (*Quality Assurance*).

Ela não aparece no nível de testes automatizados no estilo *xUnit* porque, numa analogia, o Driver seria o próprio código do teste unitário, o qual não precisa de nome especial - ele é apenas o código de testes :-)

Answer (score 2):

### **Teste de integração**

[Teste de integração](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teste_de_integra%C3%A7%C3%A3o) é a fase do teste de software em que módulos são combinados e testados em grupo. Ela sucede o teste de unidade, em que os módulos são testados individualmente, e antecede o teste de sistema, em que o sistema completo (integrado) é testado num ambiente que simula o ambiente de produção.

No contexto de teste de integração, usamos os elementos **stubs** e **drivers**

- **Stubs** são pseudo-implementações de determinadas especificações (Casos básicos/triviais/esperados)
- **Drivers** são operações que automatizam testes de acordo com casos de teste

### **Top-down**

Como se pode perceber pelo próprio nome, usando a técnica Top-down, o teste começa do nível mais alto para o mais baixo, ou seja, os componentes de mais alto nível são integrados primeiro. O teste usa driver e stubs:

- O driver é utilizado como módulo de controle principal, e os módulos reais são substituídos por stubs
- À medida que os testes vão sendo realizados os stubs são substituídos pelos módulos reais, um de cada vez.

**Vantagens**

- Permite verificação antecipada de comportamento de alto nível
- Um único driver é necessário
- Módulos podem ser adicionados, um por vez, em cada passo, se desejado
- Suporta ambas as abordagens ‘‘breadth first’’ e ‘‘depth first’’

**Desvantagens**

- Retarda verificação de comportamento de baixo nível
- Stubs são necessários para suprir elementos ainda inexistentes
- Entradas de casos de teste podem ser difíceis de formular
- Saídas de casos de teste podem ser difíceis de interpretar

  - Oráculos podem ser necessários para inspecionar resultados esperados

### **Bottom-up**

A integração é feita a partir do nível mais básico da hierarquia. Os stubs nem sempre são necessários.

- Os módulos do nível inferior são combinados.
- Para cada combinação é criado um driver que coordena a entrada e a saída dos casos de teste.
- O módulo é testado
- O driver é substituído pela combinação de módulos correspondentes, que passam a interagir com os módulos do nível superior

**Vantagens**

- Permite verificação antecipada de comportamento de baixo nível
- Stubs não são necessários
- Mais fácil para formular dados de entrada para algumas sub-árvores
- Mais fácil para interpretar dados de saída para outras sub-árvores

**Desvantagens**

- Retarda verificação de comportamento de  alto nível
- Drivers são necessários para elementos ainda não implementados
- Como sub-árvores são combinadas, um grande número de elementos deve ser integrado de uma só vez

Referência:

- Livros Engenharia de Software - 9ª Edição 2011 - Ian Sommerville