# Qual a utilidade da funcionalidade "Add Fakes Assembly"?

Tags: visual-studio, testes

Além da utilidade, como podemos implementá-la?

Não encontrei documentação em português que esclarecesse essa funcionalidade muito menos exemplos de como aplicá-la.

[image: Visual Studio]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sabe o que é um [Fake](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/36745/101)? Tem [documentação sobre o assunto](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2015/test/isolating-code-under-test-with-microsoft-fakes?view=vs-2015&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Então adicionando esse *assembly* está capacitando o projeto para ser testável com um mecanismo que simula os mecanismos mais complexos que não são adequados para rodar durante um teste através de *mocks* e *shims*.

Comment: Vou considerar como resposta mesmo sem algum exemplo (entendo que não vai ser simples exemplificar um caso) levando em conta a boa explicação sobre Fake (inclusive as correlacionadas existentes no site) - com elas tentarei criar meu próprio teste.

Comment: @ismael é que aí vai ficar muito ampla, mas se tiver dúvidas específicas quando estiver criando pode postar que a gente tenta responder.