# Erro ao tentar utilizar XUnit

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Estou tentando utilizar `XUnit` para fazer o teste de minha aplicação, mas estou recebendo esse erro na hora da `injeção de dependência`. Recebo o seguinte erro:

> Message: The following constructor parameters did not have matching fixture data: ICompetitionService competitionManager

Classe de  `Teste`:

```
public class CampeonatoTest
{
    private const string IdReturnsOk = "2021";
    private const string IdNotFound = "XXXX";

    private readonly CampeonatosController _campeonato;

    private readonly ICompetitionService _competitionManager;

    public CampeonatoTest(
        ICompetitionService competitionManager)
    {
        _competitionManager = competitionManager;

        _campeonato = new CampeonatosController(_competitionManager);
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task Campeonato_GetById_ValuesReturnsOkResponse()
    {
        var response = await _campeonato.Get(IdReturnsOk);

        var objectResponse = response as ObjectResult;

        Assert.Equal(200, objectResponse.StatusCode);
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task Campeonato_GetById_ReturnsNotFoundResponse()
    {
        var response = await _campeonato.Get(IdNotFound);

        var objectResponse = response as ObjectResult;

        Assert.Equal(404, objectResponse.StatusCode);
    }
}
```

E essa é minha `Controller`:

```
private readonly ICompetitionService _competitionManager;

public CampeonatosController(ICompetitionService competitionManager) 
{
    _competitionManager = competitionManager;
}
```

Oque estou fazendo de errado ?

Answer (score 0):

Cara, analisando o teu código o problema está na sua classe de teste tentando receber a instancia de um ICompetitionService.

Acredito que você está misturando alguns conceitos, pois quando falamos de testes de unidades, você deveria isolar a unidade a ser testada de suas dependências. Do jeito que está, você está esperando uma implementação real de ICompetitionService.

Isso traz alguns problemas para seu teste, como por exemplo, se o ICompetitionService acessa o banco de dados ou uma api externa, ou alguma dependência ICompetitionService faz esses tipos de acessos, você tem que garantir que o banco de dados e a api vão esta de pé e disponíveis para seu teste passar e que eles tenham o comportamento exato que seu teste espera.

Um jeito de resolver esse problema é você simular o comportamento de suas dependências através de Mocks ou Stubs, ao invés de você chamar sua dependência real você vai passar um objeto que irá simular o comportamento da sua dependência, talvez retornando o(s) dado(s) que seu teste espera ou lançando alguma exceção.

Para entender a dif de Mock e Stubs, veja está outra thread: [Qual a diferença entre mock & stub?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/36745/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-mock-stub)

Veja também essa lib: https://github.com/moq/moq4