# Como funciona o teste de implementação?

Tags: testes

Estava lendo a [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/36756/27190) do Maniero a respeito de teste de software e teve um ponto na resposta que me deixou com dúvida, portanto eu gostaria de uma explicação mais detalhada a respeito.

A citação que me deixou com dúvida foi:

> Só reforço que pensar bem na sua arquitetura e testar sua
>   implementação é fundamental.

A dúvida é a respeito do teste de implementação, eu gostaria de saber como é feito este tipo de teste e qual o objetivo dele para aplicação? Também gostaria de saber qual a relação que este teste tem com a arquitetura da aplicação?

Se possível colocar algum exemplo para facilitar a ilustração.

Comment: Só quero dizer que a intenção ali não era falar sobre a técnica específica que usa esse nome :) Por isso, apesar da dúvida ter surgido ali não acho que ela sirva de base para responder, é melhor focar na metodologia conhecida.

Comment: @Maniero o foco é a metodologia msm xD