# Teste de integração e acesso ao banco de dados

Tags: php, mysqli, testes, testes-automatizados, phpunit

Tenho uma aplicação (API) desenvolvida em PHP estou precisando executar alguns testes de integração nas rotas da mesma.

Detalhes da aplicação:

Linguagem: PHP

Framework: Slim

A aplicação não utiliza nenhuma ORM, todas as *querys* são feitas na mão, também é utilizado `mysqli`, também não é utilizado nenhuma ferramenta de migrations.

A duvida é sobre o Banco de Dados, existe alguma maneira de fazer a aplicação consumir um banco em memoria (SQLite) para otimizar os teste utilizando o `mysqli`? Se não, eu já consigo realizar os testes com um banco em disco MySQL, porém me surge outra dúvida.

O banco deve estar inicialmente vazio para cada teste e vamos supor que uma das minhas rotas cria algum recurso no banco, após o teste como posso volta-lo para o estado inicial?

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parabéns por manter o sistema simples (ou quase).

Para aplicar testes da forma como deseja terá que deixar de fazer o sistema ser simples.

Eu não sou contra testes formais, claro, eles são bons e úteis. Mas eles cobram um preço. Não existe sistema testado desta forma que consiga ficar impune, você tem criar um pouco de complexidade, colocar penduricalhos no código para atender a demanda do teste em vez de atender a necessidade do negócio e da aplicação em si.

Quando vai testar da forma como as pessoas pregam, não pode pesar, então o acesso ao banco de dados pode ser proibitivo.

E tem que pensar se quer testar a aplicação ou o acesso ao banco de dados. Em alguns casos até o SQLite pode ser pesado demais para testar a aplicação. O teste do banco de dados tem que ser com o próprio.

Existem [mecanismos para auxiliar o teste](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/36756/101) e dar o resultado que espera. Mas você tem que implementá-los no código.

Então, não, o SQLite, apesar de ter sido criado justamente para fazer o que deseja, não pode ser acessado pelo `mysqli` que, por óbvio, foi criado para acessar o MySQL, tem que existir um mecanismo que troque isto para testar, conforme os parágrafos anteriores.

Para começar a base do zero a forma mais simples é [*droppar*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/drop-database.html) o que foi usado e [importar a base de referência](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqlimport.html) ([outra opção](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-command-options.html), e [mais uma](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html)). Precisa criar um código para automatizar.

Tudo isto independe de linguagem ou *framework* usado. Obviamente que a implementação dos mecanismos de substituição serão específicos para a linguagem.

Talvez seja útil ver [Qual é a diferença de API, biblioteca e Framework?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17501/101), já que a maioria confundo o que é uma API, porque o "mercado" começou usar o nome de forma equivocada.